# How to include jQuery locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When tested using CDNs eveything is wporking perfectly however I can't manage to use jquery/jquery mobile locally. Sometimes some of the classes seem to work and not others, and sometimes not at all.

Using these versions:
jQuery - 3.2.1
jQuery Mobile - 1.4.5

## I've tried:

Loading them in the order of Jquery, then mobile, then my js file.
Putting the jQuery files inside the css and js folders.
Linking to the files with and without a / before the css/js folders

## SOLVED EDIT:

Currently the most recent versions of jQuery and jQuery mobile are not compatible. When using a CDN I was using an older version which was why it was working. I locally added an older version of jQuery and it worked.

HEAD:

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> <!-- Link to main style sheet -->
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

My directory:

https://gyazo.com/8c41761abf2cd0d4e006e6e032d2a0f4

If I attempt to run everything as above I get the following console error (jQuery mob line 4):

> TypeError: a.event.props is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your browser console? that can be a good start to see what the kind of error you're facing, you can see the browser console pressing the ***F12*** key and then you have to go to the section Network, once you opened it  reload the page and you will be able to see why is not loading your JS file.[image: Console of Google Chrome]

Comment: Here is an image of the network tab, doesn't even say that the files weren't found https://gyazo.com/d3087d4ca4f34f75a10242f4fe2acf06

Comment: If you can share your code it would be more easy to debug it.

Comment: I don't see any reference corrupt, but in the console is not showing your JS even if you would had the wrong references the console is not throwing you any error, I recommend to you for now to delete the html comments(CDN references) and to create a new folder and put your JS files there, and type the new JS references such as:

    _<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>_
    _<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>_ and see what the console is returning